# What should I do if i want this button can be only clicked by admin

Tags: php, html

I have done some researches but i cant find a proper answer

I want that button can only be clicked by admin, if that button clicked my a normal user an alert box will appeared

Or perhaps that button will only appeared if logged in as admin?

```
<a href="view.php" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Admin button</a>
```

This is my admin button ↑

My admin information from my database is:

```
userid: 3
username: admin
password: admin
role: 0
```

Should I include ↓

```
<?php
session_start()
include "connection.php"

if(empty($_SESSION['role'] == '0')){
echo "xxx";
}
else
{
echo "xxx";
}
?>
```

If so, what should i write within the "xxx"?

The connection.php will be:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","gallery");

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    die("<script>alert('Error in connection !');window.history.go(-1);</script>");
}
echo "<script>alert('Successfully connected !');</script>";
?>
```

Comment: Don't you think is best to render the button **only** when the user is admin? In this case you will have just an `if` to check `role == 0` and render the button

Comment: your button is an anchor, it means you will be redirected in another page, if you want to implement an alert system, you have to use ```AJAX``` tech

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start()
include "connection.php"

if(empty($_SESSION['role'])
&& $_SESSION['role'] == '0'){
    echo "<p><a href='view.php' class='btn btn-info' role='button'>Admin button</a></p>";
}
?>
```

It should be like above condition.

In your code, empty function and equality condition is not correct.

Comment: Thanks bro, but the "if" line and "&&" line should be in the same line for it to work. Btw, can i ask how to hide the button from a non-user and non-admin?

Comment: Yes it can be on same line. Its different coding style. If this answer solves your issue, you can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

If your only intentions are to hide the button for non-admin users then its very simple, and you don't need an `else` logic operator for this. Since if the condition isn't met. Don't do anything

```php
<?php
session_start()
include "connection.php"

if(empty($_SESSION['role'] == '0')){
echo "<p><a href='view.php' class='btn btn-info' role='button'>Admin button</a></p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I tried this code, but I have to change to role == 1, then only that button will not appeared when logged in as normal user, is that any wrong with my code?

Comment: And also, how about if the people who browse the site is neither a user nor admin? What should I do to hide the button from him/her?

Answer (score 0):

You can use session variable "role" and javascript function to do that.

**Javascript:**

Add this script in your head or footer

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkUser(type) {
    if (type == '0') { // User is Admin move to view
        window.location("view.php");
    } else {
        alert("Hey! You are not admin");
    }
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

In your page change your link to button as:

```
<?php
session_start();
include "connection.php" ?>

<button class='btn btn-info' role='button' onclick="checkUser(<?php if($_SESSION['role'] == '0'){
  echo '0';
  } else {
    echo '1';
  } ?>

);" >Admin button</button>
```

Comment: The button do appear there but do not give respond when clicked

Comment: Edited my answer. Have you added javascript as well?